# What are the priority values in the EventPriority event?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

What are the values of the constants in the Flex EventPriority class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EventPriority.CURSOR_MANAGEMENT;    200
EventPriority.BINDING;              100
EventPriority.DEFAULT;              0
EventPriority.DEFAULT_HANDLER;     -50
EventPriority.EFFECT;              -100
```

Comment: Thanks for documenting this! I couldn't find this information anywhere and it's not listed in ASDocs. You're a life saver.